# How can I study the limit :$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{[x]}{\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions, indeterminate-forms

How can I study the limit of the following function?
$$\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}
\frac{[x]}{\sin x}
\end{equation*}$$

Any hint will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: what does $[x]$ mean? floor function?

Comment: @Siong Yes, it means the greatest integer function in many countries. That is the floor function.

Comment: @samjoe thanks. I usually use $\lfloor \rfloor$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to evaluate both **right** and **left** hand limits here, as $[x]$ (floor function) is not continuous at $x = 0$:

1. If $x \in [0,1)$, then $[x] = 0$. So the *right hand limit* is simply $0$.
2. If $x \in (-1, 0)$, then $[x] = -1$. The *left hand   limit* is:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{-1}{ \sin(x)} =\infty$$

From here we see the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

For $0<x<1 $

$$
\frac{[x]}{\sin x} =0 $$
Hence

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}
\frac{[x]}{\sin x}=0
\end{equation*}
Whereas for $-1<x<0$

$$
\frac{[x]}{\sin x} =
\frac{-1}{\sin x}  $$

Thus 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-}
\frac{[x]}{\sin x}=\infty
\end{equation*} does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

For a limit to exist, the limit, by definition should be

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow n^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow n^-}f(x)=L$$

It is easy to note that this does not apply for this case since

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{[x]}{\sin x}=0 $$
And
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{[x]}{\sin x}=-1$$